# Add and implement a spinner in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, spinner

I have seen guides and tutorials implementing spinner for activities. However the same method doesn't work for fragments. This was my code inside the `onCreateView` method of a fragment class

```
val personnames = arrayOf("akshat" , "mourya")
    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, personnames)
    spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :

    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {

            spinnerText.text = personnames[position]
        }
```

When the `ArrayAdapter` method is called on line 2, I get a type mismatch error because the first parameter requires a context and in my code it is a fragment.
I tried doing the same thing in the activity and it worked. 
Fragment are supposed to be like mini activities, so why this error propping up?

Also is there any way I can add spinner to my Fragment?

Comment: Pass `requireContext()` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **requireContext()** in place of **this** in line 2.

Like this:

```
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, personnames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
 val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, personnames)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` is not a subclass of `Context` so you can't pass `this` as the first argument of the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.
When you need a `Context` object inside a `Fragment` you need to use either one of the two functions `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()`.